# How to rename the sub files in a folder with the name of the parent file plus some index using python

Tags: python, string, file, rename, subdirectory

I have files in the parent directory as given:

```
parent_folder
 |-file1
    |-img1.jpg
    |-img2.jpg
    |-img3.jpg
 |-file2
    |-img1.jpg
    |-img2.jpg
    |-img3.jpg
```

I want to rename the .jpg files by adding the name of the parent folder to it in Python. How to go about it?

```
parent_folder
 |-file1
    |-file1_img1.jpg
    |-file1_img2.jpg
    |-file1_img3.jpg
 |-file2
    |-file2_img1.jpg
    |-file2_img2.jpg
    |-file2_img3.jpg
```

i tried the following code but its not working:

```
def naming():
    path='D:/parent_folder'
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        print(files)
        for name in files:
            print(name)
            newname = files + name
            os.rename(join(root,name),join(root,newname))
```

Comment: Use `os.rename()` and `os.walk()`

Comment: I have tried it but  get  error at newname=files+name , please check the edited question

Comment: What Python version are you using? If you are on Python 3.4+, please consider using [```pathlib```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). I can provide a pathlib example if you have that.

Comment: python 3.7, please provide example

Comment: @mumtaz Done. Check my answer and its proof of concept.

Comment: Provide the error, also join() is not a build-in function is a string method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in Python 3.4+ should work:

```
from pathlib import Path

parent_folder = Path('d:/parent_folder')

for obj in parent_folder.glob('*'):
    if obj.is_dir():
        for jpg in obj.glob('*.jpg'):
            jpg.rename(jpg.parent / f'{jpg.parent.name}_{jpg.name}')
```

If your Python interpreter doesn't support `f-strings`, use this alternative version:

```
from pathlib import Path

parent_folder = Path('d:/parent_folder')

for obj in parent_folder.glob('*'):
    if obj.is_dir():
        for jpg in obj.glob('*.jpg'):
            jpg.rename(jpg.parent / '{0}_{1}'.format(jpg.parent.name, jpg.name))
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```
$ cat ren.py 
from pathlib import Path

parent_folder = Path('testdir')

for obj in parent_folder.glob('*'):
    if obj.is_dir():
        for jpg in obj.glob('*.jpg'):
            jpg.rename(jpg.parent / f'{jpg.parent.name}_{jpg.name}')
$ tree testdir
testdir
├── dir1
│   ├── file1.jpg
│   └── file2.jpg
└── dir2
    ├── file1.jpg
    └── file2.jpg

2 directories, 4 files
$ python3 ren.py 
$ tree testdir
testdir
├── dir1
│   ├── dir1_file1.jpg
│   └── dir1_file2.jpg
└── dir2
    ├── dir2_file1.jpg
    └── dir2_file2.jpg

2 directories, 4 files
$
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: jpg.rename(jpg.parent / f'{jpg.parent.name}_{jpg.name}')
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It is working fine here. There is no syntax error on that line BTW. Does your Python interpreter implements ```f-strings```? Do a simple test like ```print(f'test')```.

Comment: It is just a guess (since I don't have a Windows machine to test it) but maybe the slash operator doesn't work on Windows. Replace that line with ```jpg.rename(Path(jpg.parent, f'{jpg.parent.name}_{jpg.name}'))```.

Comment: Anyway, I don't believe either of my guesses are the problem. ```f-strings``` and ```pathlib``` are standards and they should work on any OS where Python runs.

Comment: print(f'test') 
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax and  jpg.rename(Path(jpg.parent, f'{jpg.parent.name}_{jpg.name}'))
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @mumtaz, I've added an alternative version to workaround that.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
import os
import glob

path_l = glob.glob('/**/*.jpg', recursive=True)
for path in path_l:
    path_splitted = path.split('/')
    file_name = path_splitted[-1]
    dir_name = path_splitted[-2]
    new_name = dir_name + '_' + file_name
    new_path = path.replace(file_name, new_name)
    os.rename(path, new_path)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That should work as well but compare it with my ```pathlib``` example and you will never want to use ```os``` and ```glob.glob()``` again. :-D

Comment: path_l = glob.glob('/**/*.jpg') What path should be give in it? It seems to run but does not give any result.

Comment: @mumtaz you must give the root dir path. For example: `<path_to_parent_folder>/**/*.jpg`

Comment: @mumtaz or if you run the script from `parent_folder` the script should work.

Comment: **path_l **= glob.glob('C:/Users/dee/Desktop/parent/**/*.jpg')
**path split prints**:['C:', 'Users', 'dee', 'Desktop', 'parent\\folder_three\\image_24.jpg']
**file_name prints** parent\folder_three\image_24.jpg, **dir_name** : Desktop
**new_name**:Desktop_parent\folder_three\image_24.jpg,

Comment: **new_path**
C:/Users/deebh/Desktop/Desktop_parent\folder_three\image_24.jpg  **os.rename(path, new_path)
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified**

Comment: @mumtaz try this: 
`file_name = 'parent\folder_three\image_24.jpg'`
`splitted = file_name.split('\')`
`new_name = splitted[-2] + splitted[-1]`
and print `new_name` please